# Having problems figuring out AJAX POST functions

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, .htaccess

I am trying to post using AJAX because I don't want to use a submit button and reload the page everytime I click it.
I am using this code for ajax:

```
<script language="JavaScript"><!--

function postit()
{
    var frm = $('#pmconfirm');
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "bitcin",
    data: frm.serialize(),

    success: function(msg){
    $("#main").hide();
    $("#main").html(msg).show();
    },
    error: function(msg){
    $("#main").html("<font color='#ff0000'>Ajax loading error, please try again.</font>").show();
    }

    });
}

setTimeout("postit()",2000);

//--></script>
```

Next,  I am using this form:

```
<form action="" name="fcaptcha" method="post">

<input type="hidden" id="bitcoin" name="bitcoin">

<input type="hidden" id="pmconfirm" name="pmconfirm" src="http://www.mvixusa.com/newsletter/2010/11/newsletter-membership-confirmation/images/confirm-button.png" alt="Submit Form" onclick=\"document.getElementById("fcaptcha").submit()\"/>
  </form>
<div id="main">
</div>
```

This works it posts but I doesn't give me results ?

```
if (isset($_POST['bitcoin']))
{
 // My code here works, because it works when i dont use ajax
 // And I have some things to check like if it wasnt what i wanted 
 // it returns some message which is shown with php.
}

<div id="messaget">
<?php
if($failed == 1) echo $messages; 
?>
</div>
```

This is the part where the messages should be displayed, I tried using a tag #messaget   to display the HTML after post but it didn't work, I tried displaying the entire page in this page it still didn't work.

And the url: "bitcin",        is entirely ok, i used htaccess.
Can somebody spot where the problem is ?

Comment: You're trying to serialize a form element, rather than the form here `data: frm.serialize()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an id to the form :

```
<form id="pmform" action="" name="fcaptcha" method="post">
```

And change Js to:

```
var frm = $('#pmform');
```

When performing:

```
............
data: frm.serialize(), //this will take the form and make an array based on the names of the form elements thus having them accessible in the PHP script
..........
```

Comment: FYI, the OP doesn't really need to add an id, he can use an attribute selector `var frm = $('form[name="fcaptcha"]')`

Comment: Indeed but id selectors, from what i know, are faster because they are unique ... either way

Comment: Name selectors are just as fast, just requires a little more typing and should be unique too. A lot depends on the size of the overall DOM structure.

Comment: Hello,
Thank you, this seems to be working but still the php is unfunctional, because it's supposed to update database data and it doesnt.
It only shows me a result when I use a button and then try the ajax one manually with this <input type="submit" onclick="postit();" ?>
But it doesnt get the message itself without reloading the page :(